# C++ How to output number with at least one number behind the decimal mark

Tags: c++, numbers, decimal

How can I make my program output a number with at least one number behind the decimal mark C++?
Output:
1 = 1.0 or 1.25 = 1.25 or 2.2 = 2.2 or 3.456789 = 3.456789

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `showpoint` to force the decimal point to be printed

```
double x = 1.0;
std::cout << std::showpoint << x << "\n";
```

It will be followed by the number of `0` required to satisfy the precision of the stream.

Comment: std::showpoint does not guarantee that any zeros will be output after the point, only that the point will be output. You could end up with '1.' if the precision of the stream had been set to 1.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/showpoint/

Comment: @mxsscott: Agreed. You need to make sure the precisions of the stream is correct (or what you want) as well. There is no perfect solution to this problem because of the way formatting is done.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

struct FormatFloat
{
    static constexpr const double precision = std::sqrt(std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon());
    const double value;
    FormatFloat(double value) : value(value) {}
    void write(std::ostream& stream) const {
        std::streamsize n = 0;
        double f = std::abs(value - (long long)value);
        while(precision < f) {
            f *= 10;
            f -= (long long)f;
            ++n;
        }
        if( ! n) n = 1;
        n = stream.precision(n);
        std::ios_base::fmtflags flags = stream.setf(
            std::ios_base::fixed,
            std::ios_base::floatfield);
        stream << value;
        stream.flags(flags);
        stream.precision(n);
    }
};

inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const FormatFloat& value) {
    value.write(stream);
    return stream;
}

inline FormatFloat format_float(double value) {
    return FormatFloat(value);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout
        << format_float(1) << '\n'
        << format_float(1.25) << '\n'
        << format_float(2.2) << '\n'
        << format_float(3.456789) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice: Two things I would personally change. 1) Get rid of `format_float()` function. The stream operator is passed it by const value so you can declare them as you use them. 2) Remove the `write()` method. Just put the `operator<<` into the class (as a friend) and you can write it in place. See: http://pastebin.com/gSpnn8f0

Comment: Also `inline` is useless keyword. Only use it if you must. The only time it is needed is to let the linker know their are multiple versions of a function because you have defined the function in the header file, and with most modern compilers now supporting full program optimization that is unnecessary.

Comment: @LokiAstari The format_float is for maintenance (Maybe, FormatFloat becomes a template).

Comment: Sure. Then lets follow convention. When you write simple template deductions functions the convention is to call it `make_X` where X is the name of the type. `make_pair`, `make_unique`, `make_shared` etc.. Also the requirement for this is going away with C++14 I believe where template parameter deduction is being extended to the constructor arguments of a class.

Comment: @LokiAstari That is way over the top for a stream manipulator!

Comment: Which bit? Saying that we should follow conventions or another thing I said earlier. Anyway probably true for both. :-)

Comment: This gives some pretty absurd values for some input [http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07af8b93b96da9f6](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07af8b93b96da9f6)

Answer (score 1):

*If you're going to call this function a lot, then this probably isn't what you're looking for because this isn't the best way to do it, but it does work.*

Something along the lines of:

```
string text = to_string(55);
if (text.find(".") != std::string::npos) {
    cout << "No digit added after decimal point" << text;
}
else
{
    cout << "Digit added after decimal point" << text << ".0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double value = ...;
std::ostringstream ss;
ss.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 2);
ss << value;
std::string s = ss.str();
if (s.find('.') == string::npos)
{
    s.append(".0");
}
```

or

```
double value = ...;
std::wostringstream ss;
ss.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 2);
ss << value;
std::wstring s = ss.str();
if (s.find(L'.') == string::npos)
{
    s.append(L".0");
}
```