# Digits after decimal points in printing outputs

Tags: c++11, formatting

I need to do the following computations.

```
sqrt(abs(pow(a, 2) - pow(b, 2)))
sqrt(abs(pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2)))
```

Let `a = 4` and `b = 5` so the outputs are `3` and `6.40312`. Now if I want to print like `3.0` and other one kept as same `6.40312` how can I do that? If I use `setprecision()` and `fixed` the outputs are `3.0000`and `6.40312`. How can I have varible lenght decimal points results with `cout`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ How to output number with at least one number behind the decimal mark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645778/c-how-to-output-number-with-at-least-one-number-behind-the-decimal-mark)

Comment: Also note that `pow(a, 2)` is a very inefficient way of doing `a*a`.